# Electromagnetic waves in medium with strange polarization vector

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

I have an exercise in Electromagnetic waves, basically to find the refractive index of a wave in a medium with polarization $\mathbf{P}=\alpha \nabla \times \mathbf{E}$. I used the Maxwell equations inside a material and assuming a plane wave, I got the following system of equations:
\begin{align*}
(-k^{2}+\frac{\omega^{2}}{c^{2}})E_{0y}=-i\alpha\mu_{0}k\omega^{2}E_{0x}\\
(-k^{2}+\frac{\omega^{2}}{c^{2}})E_{0x}=i\alpha\mu_{0}k\omega^{2}E_{0y}\\
\end{align*}
where $E_{0x},E_{0y}$, are the x,y components of the magnitude of the plane EM wave. I solved the system by assuming circular polarization. This gave 2 possible indexes for $E_{0x}=\pm iE_{0y}$. My question is if this is the most generic solution I could get, I am not quite satisfied because I get two possible $n$ one for left and one for right handed polarizations.
Although this is a question that came from an exercise, I would also like a general answer about the nature of such a material (if it exists). I find it very strange for a polarization to depend on the curl.

Comment: since the polarization violates parity conservation, maybe you should get different answers for L and R?

Comment: @JEB Oh thank you I completely missed that observation.

Comment: Is this a "trick" problem, with a supposedly polar vector polarization equal to an axial vector (curl of a polar vector)?

Comment: @JEB Honestly the question is pretty poorly stated and it just says to find the refractive index in a material with that given vector polarization. I haven't seen something similar in Griffiths for example, that's the reason I asked if someone knows if a material can even be modeled by such polarization. Your comment made me think about the axial nature of the curl and now it's even stranger that a can material violate the parity symmetry.

Comment: This problem reminds me of microwave ferrites that have antisymmetric [susceptibility tensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polder_tensor), where the skew-tensor describes the linear relationship between the dynamic (small signal) magnetization and field intensity. Here you have a linear differential relationship between the polarization vector and the antisymmetric derivative (curl) of the field intensity. I am only pointing out *some* analogy without claiming anything "deep".

Comment: @hyportnex I will look it up, it actually somewhat reminded me of the Faraday effect  where the rotation is induced by the polarization and not an external magnetic field.

Comment: the skew symmetry of  the susceptibility tensor is the basis of all microwave ferrite devices (circulators, isolators, limiters, switches, etc.) including the Faraday effect, they all take advantage of the dependence of the refractive index on the direction of propagation.